# Não consegui traduzir o plugin FullCalendar para pt-br. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

boa tarde.
Estou querendo usar o fullcalendar em software web, porém não estou conseguindo traduzir para português.
Já importei o arquivo pt-br.js e adicionei um script JS, porém sem exito. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Dá uma olhada: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/locale

Answer (score 1):

Quando você baixou o fullcalendar provavelmente tinha uma pasta chamada **locale** junto aos arquivos, nessa pasta contém os idiomas.
Faça a referência do arquivo **pt-br.js** junto a referência do fullcalendar.

**Exemplo:**

```
<script src='fullcalendar/fullcalendar.js'></script>
<script src='fullcalendar/locale/pt-br.js'></script>
<script>

    $(function() {

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
           lang: 'pt-br'
        });

    });

</script>
```